# Bluetooth4.0 vs WiFi in a Android to arduino connection

Tags: android

I've read this article 
http://gtms1313.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/bluetooth4-0-vs-wi-fi-direct/

which is a good summary of latest Wifi vs Bluetooth technologies, but the actual hardware being used needs to be taken into account. I need to hack an Android which will also connect wirelessly to an arduino. Will the communication be easier with Bluetooth from a coding and serial access point of view?

Comment: What sort of 'communication' are you planning? What information/data are you planning to communicate? Do you require one-way or two-way communication? The answers to these questions may determine whether Classic Bluetooth or Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) is the better path to follow.

Comment: One way. Primarily cycling, triggering of lights and light levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wifi-Direct has not been widely used yet, even with inclusion into Android 4.0. You will not find any direct modules for the Arduino that support wifi-direct.

Bluetooth 4.0, normally refers to Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) connections. BLE is not backwards compatible with Bluetooth Classic (i.e. Bluetooth 2.0 or 3.0), unless the device supports Dual Mode (Both BLE and Classic). There are BLE Shields. Your phone must support Bluetooth 4.0 LE connections. Otherwise, you would connect with Bluetooth Classic, which is pretty power intensive compared to BLE.

Answer (score 0):

Probably no clear answer. I would choose Bluetooth as there is a solution already available:

http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/